# Set custom global variables in Caddyfile

Tags: caddy

I have multiple `reverse_proxy` entries that share the same destination host. Isn't there a way to set a global variable inside the Caddyfile in order to reuse it?

```
app1.dns {
    reverse_proxy myhost:xxxx
}

app2.dns {
    reverse_proxy myhost:yyyy
}

app3.dns {
    reverse_proxy myhost:zzzz
}
```

Comment: Here in the current example, there are different values you have configured. Please update your example with repeated values.

Answer (score 2):

## Caddy Snippets

The re-usable global configuration is possible to define once use anywhere within caddyfile, example here

```
(snippet) {
  respond "Yahaha! You found {args.0}!"
}

(hello) {
  respond "Hello {args.0}!"
}

a.example.com {
  import snippet "Example A"
}

b.example.com {
  import hello "World"
}
```